# Disable STP in Opensolaris bridge

Tags: networking, opensolaris, bridge, stp

how can i completely disable STP in a Opensolaris bridge.

This bridge is connected to a Cisco Access Port and will disable the uplink port when the first BPDU arrives.

```
bridged[3651]: [ID 581644 daemon.warning] unexpected BPDU on rge1 from 0:xx:xx:xx:xx:b; forwarding disabled
```

I already disabled the transmission of BPDU Messages to the Switch by:

```
dladm set-linkprop -p stp=0 rge1
```

This solved only the problem that the access switch port goes in "error-disable" mode.

Thomas

Comment: It seams there is no way to disable stp complete.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to disable Spanning Tree? STP is enabled for a reason to stop layer 2 routing loops, which can cause ethernet frames to loop indefinitely!

I'm not quite sure what environment your operating or what your trying to achieve, it maybe
best to get to the bottom of the problem rather than a work around.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to de-configure `spanning-tree portfast` and `spanning-tree bpduguard enable`  on the Cisco port you're connected to. Without BPDU transmission and spanning-tree, you may end up having a switching loop and I've seen switching loops take networks down.

Comment: To err on the side of caution, I'd really do some research on those two settings before de configuring them. Perhaps talk to your network person and see what they say. If you are the network person, then get some help :-).

I've just seem some very nasty layer 2 problems be caused by the misconfiguration of layer 2 protocols!

Comment: Removing them should (at worst) mean that it takes a while (up to a minute) for a newly-plugged-in cable to become active (removing "portfast"). The "bpduguard" is configuration option should always be enabled on a port with portfast, as what portfast does is disabling BPDU snooping, trusting the port to be a non-bridge. So, in this specific case, the configuration is safe.